# Else element not returning the correct result

Tags: php, html, join, mysqli

I have created a select statement using php to return results to an HTML based on user input. The feedback is returned based on the input fields matching fields in a manually populated table. The select statement should return the highest ID. The form inserts data into the 'adoption' table. The results then return a row from the 'dogs' table based on the fields below matching in the 'adoption' table.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ncdr_first", "3308");

$sql = "SELECT dogs.name, dogs.breed, dogs.age, dogs.sex, dogs.image, adoption.adoption_id 
        FROM dogs 
            INNER JOIN adoption ON dogs.adultRadio = adoption.adultRadio 
                AND dogs.child = adoption.child 
                AND dogs.petRadio = adoption.petRadio 
                AND dogs.pet = adoption.pet 
                AND dogs.activity = adoption.activity 
                AND dogs.home = adoption.home 
                AND dogs.environment = adoption.environment
        ORDER BY adoption.adoption_id DESC 
        LIMIT 0, 1";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

?>
```

The results are then displayed in a table in the HTML section of the page.

```
<div class="table">
    <center><table id="feedback">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Breed</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Sex</th>
                <th>Image</th>
            </tr>
    <?php
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["breed"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["age"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["sex"];?></td>  
            <td><img src="<?php echo $row["image"];?>"/></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }

    } else {
        echo "Unfortunately you have not been a match for any of our furry friends! Please try again soon.";
    }   
    ?>
    </center></table>


CREATE TABLE dogs (dog_id int, name varchar, breed varchar, age varchar, sex 
varchar, adultRadio varchar, child varchar, petRadio varchar, pet varchar, 
activity varchar, home varchar, environment varchar, image varchar ); 

CREATE TABLE adoption (adoption_id int, name varchar, address varchar, 
adultRadio varchar, child varchar, petRadio varchar, pet varchar, activity 
varchar, home varchar, environment varchar, image varchar );
```

However, if I input data to the 'adoption' table that doesn't match any of the rows in the 'dogs' table it will return the row that was last matched instead of the statement in the else. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

```
<?php
session_start();

//Check if user is logged in, if not redirect to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
header("location: login.php");
exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="eng">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="view" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>North Coast Dog Rescue Contact Page</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Responsive website for North Coast Dog 
 Rescue"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Chloe Leighton B00710338"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<style type="text/css">
    .formContainer #adultNo:checked ~ .conditional, #petYes:checked ~ .conditional {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
    }

    .formContainer #adultNo:not(:checked) ~ .conditional, #petYes:not(:checked) ~ .conditional {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
            </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="about"><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="dogs"><a href="dogs.html">Dogs for Adoption</a></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="adoptionForm.php">Online Adoption Form</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="login"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<form action="adoptionForm.php" method="post">

        <div class="formContainer">
    <h1>Adoption Form</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to be matched to a suitable dog.</p>
    <hr/>

            <label><b>Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="name"/>

            <label><b>Address</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="address"/>

            <label><b>Do you have an adult only home?</b></label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="adultRadio" id="adultYes" value="Yes" onclick="radio_check()"; /> Yes <br />
    <input type="radio" name="adultRadio" id="adultNo" value="No" onclick="radio_check()"; /> No <br />

    <div class="conditional">
        <label><b>If you don't have an adult only home, please select the age of any children: </b></label><br />
        <select id="child" size="0" name="child">
            <option value="" name=""></option>
            <option value="baby/toddler" name="baby/toddler">Baby/Toddler (0-4 years)</option>
            <option value="youngChild" name="youngChild">Small Child (5-12 years)</option>
            <option value="olderChild" name="olderChild">Older Child (13-18 years)</option>
        </select><br /> 
    </div>

    <label><b>Do you have any pets?</b></label><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="petRadio" id="petYes" value="Yes" onclick="radio_check()";/> Yes <br />
    <input type="radio" name="petRadio" id="petNo" value="No" onclick="radio_check()";/> No <br />

    <div class="conditional"> 
        <label><b>If you have a pet, please select the description that fits them best: </b></label><br />
        <select id="pet" name="pet"> 
            <option value="" name=""></option>
            <option value="youngDog" name="youngDog">Young, playful dog</option>
            <option value="oldDog" name="oldDog">Older, calm dog</option>
            <option value="cat" name="cat">Cat</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <label><b>Please select which activity level fits you best: </b></label><br/>
    <select name="activity">
        <option value="notActive" name="notActive">Not very active</option>
        <option value="moderatelyActive" name="moderatelyActive">Moderately active</option>
        <option value="veryActive" name="veryActive">Very active</option>
    </select>

    <label><b>Please select how often you are at home: </b></label><br/>
    <select name="home">
        <option value="little" name="littleHome">At home very little</option>
        <option value="most" name="mostHome">At home most of the time</option>
        <option value="all" name="allHome">There is always someone at home</option>
    </select>



    <label><b>Please select which best describes your home environment: </b></label>
    <select name="environment">
        <option value="city" name="city">Busy city</option>
        <option value="suburbs" name="suburbs">Suburbs</option>
        <option value="rural" name="rural">Quiet and rural</option>
    </select>

            <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>

        </div>

        <div class="loginContainer" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
            <a href="logout.php"><button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Logout</button></a>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="footer">
        <p>North Coast Dog Rescue, Copyright &copy; 2020</p>
    </div>
</body>
    </html>

    <?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $adultRadio = $_POST['adultRadio'];
    $child = $_POST['child'];
    $petRadio = $_POST['petRadio'];
    $pet = $_POST['pet'];
    $activity = $_POST['activity'];
    $home = $_POST['home'];
    $environment = $_POST['environment'];
    $bool = true;

    //Connect to server and database
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "ncdr_first", "3308");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! <br>" ;
    echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($conn) ;

    $query_ins = "INSERT INTO adoption (name, address, adultRadio, child, 
    petRadio, pet, activity, home, environment)
    VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$adultRadio', '$child', '$petRadio', 
    '$pet', '$activity', '$home', '$environment')";

    if($bool) {
    mysqli_query($conn, $query_ins);
    echo "<script>alert('Adoption form submitted successfully!');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location.assign('feedback.php');</script>";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    }

    ?>
```

[SQL query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLDrs.png)

Comment: Please, could you post the structure of the tables dog and adoption? I have a feeling the issue is the `ON` part of your query

Comment: @JonasBouchedid hi, thanks for replying! I have edited the post to show the tables. I think that's where the issue lies too but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you always getting the same results regardless of what you submit on your form. Can you add your form code to your question.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw hi, thanks for replying! No I don't always get the same result it differs if the matching answers are different. However, if the answers aren't all matching I don't get the else statement. I have added the form code under the question.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. PS This isn't minimal. PS Isolate problems with a single framework. If necessary show levels pass data correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the SQL code it will return the last ID that matched not the last ID. You can select only the last insert with the following,

```
$sql = "SELECT dogs.name, dogs.breed, dogs.age, dogs.sex, dogs.image, adoption.adoption_id 
        FROM dogs 
            INNER JOIN adoption ON dogs.adultRadio = adoption.adultRadio 
                AND dogs.child = adoption.child 
                AND dogs.petRadio = adoption.petRadio 
                AND dogs.pet = adoption.pet 
                AND dogs.activity = adoption.activity 
                AND dogs.home = adoption.home 
                AND dogs.environment = adoption.environment
        WHERE adoption_id = (SELECT MAX(adoption_id) FROM adoption)";
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying! Unfortunately this has not worked it still displays the last matched dog.

Comment: Are you able to run the raw SQL and share the result for us?

Comment: I have posted the result of the SQL query as a screen grab.

Comment: I am not the most familiar with MySQL (which is where I now suspect the issue is)  however I suspect the issue may be with the LIMIT statement, have you tried the statement without this to verify it returns 0 results? What happens if you just use "LIMIT 1" at the end over "LIMIT 0, 1"?

Comment: if I remove the LIMIT statement and submit the form with answers that don't match it displays all of the matches that have previously occurred. If I use LIMIT 1 nothing changes.

Comment: @Chloe17 I've updated my answer to one focused on MySQL over PHP, please give that a go.